# Add multiple S3 lifecycle rules to S3 bucket with boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3, s3-lifecycle-policy

I want to add multiple lifecycle rules to a S3 bucket using lambda and boto3. However, with boto3, it only seems to allow you to add 1 lifecycle rule, which also overwrites the already existing ones.

For example, doing the following simply overwrites any pre-existing rules that I have as well as the newly written ones, and only leaves the last one in the list:

```
bucket_name = "test-bucket"
folder_paths = ["test_folder","test_folder1", "test_folder2"]
expiration = 1

for folder_path in folder_paths:
    client = boto3.client('s3')
    response = client.put_bucket_lifecycle_configuration(
        Bucket=bucket_name,
        LifecycleConfiguration={
            'Rules': [
                {
                    'Expiration': {
                        'Days': expiration
                    },
                    'ID': folder_path,
                    'Filter': {
                        'Prefix': folder_path
                    },
                    'Status': 'Enabled'
                }
            ]
        }
    )
```

Of course using the AWS console it is possible to add multiple separate S3 lifecycle configurations on a bucket.

Similarly to `put_bucket_lifecycle_configuration`, I have also tried `put_bucket_lifecycle`, which gives me the same result.

Is there any way to use boto3 to add multiple S3 lifecycle configurations on a bucket? Am I missing something obvious?

Any help is appreciated and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Of course using the AWS console it is possible to add multiple separate S3 lifecycle configurations on a bucket.

Every bucket has 1 lifecycle configuration, which can have up to 1000 rules.
Your console may show something similar:

[image]

These are not different lifecycle configurations, they are different rules part of the same lifecycle configuration.

In the input for the [`put_bucket_lifecycle_configuration`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.put_bucket_lifecycle_configuration) we can see that we can pass a list of rules, which can contain 1 ore many more (up to 1000) rules.

```
for folder_path in folder_paths:
    client = boto3.client('s3')
    response = client.put_bucket_lifecycle_configuration(
        Bucket=bucket_name,
        LifecycleConfiguration={
            'Rules': [
                {
                    'Expiration': {
                        'Days': expiration
                    },
                    'ID': id_rule_1,
                    'Filter': {
                        'Prefix': folder_path
                    },
                    'Status': 'Enabled'
                },
                {
                    'Expiration': {
                        'Days': expiration2
                    },
                    'ID': id_rule_2,
                    'Filter': {
                        'Prefix': folder_path2
                    },
                    'Status': 'Enabled'
                },
             ...
            ]
        }
    )
```

As the docs says, `put_bucket_lifecycle_configuration` "*creates a new lifecycle configuration for the bucket or replaces an existing lifecycle configuration.*" If you want to update the lifecycle configuration, you have to use [`get_bucket_lifecycle_configuration`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.get_bucket_lifecycle_configuration) to retrieve the existing rules, modify them and then use `put_bucket_lifecycle_configuration` to overwrite the existing configuration.